# ESP32: Disable Brownout Detector

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I have an ESP-WROOM-32 and I'm using Arduino IDE to push code on it. My ESP is powered via 2 AA batteries and got one power supply problem.

It works well on new battery but after a bit, I will always get this error repeatedly:

> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
>
> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0,
>   SPIWP:0xee
>   clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
>   mode:DIO, clock div:2 load:0x3fff0018,len:4 load:0x3fff001c,len:812
>   load:0x40078000,len:0 load:0x40078000,len:11584 entry 0x40078a60
>
> Brownout detector was triggered

**So, I know that it's possible to disable that feature in ESP32. My question is how to do it?**

**What I have done that didn't work:**

Add this code in my Arduino IDE:

```
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
setup(){
    WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector    
}
```

Change Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\tools\sdk\sdkconfig with:

```
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET=                //previous was "=y"
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_0=      //previous was "=y"
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_1=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_2=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_3=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_4=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_5=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_6=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_7=
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL=           //previous was "=0"
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? It's there for a reason: Your batteries are too flat to reliably power the ESP-32.

Comment: Because the manufacturer of the device told me to do it, but he's using ESP-IDF and I prefer to code with Arduino

Comment: What kind of batteries are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2 AA batteries each 1.5V

Comment: I asked what *kind*, not what *size*.  Alkeline? Zinc Carbon? NiMH?

Comment: Alkaline Plus Power by Panasonic

Comment: At 100mA average current you can expect those to last about 20 minutes before they go below the minimum voltage for the ESP-32.

Comment: Are there any batteries than I can use AA size that can power up my ESP-32 and last more than 20 minutes ?

Comment: For battery operation you have to use very aggressive power saving modes of operation.

Comment: I already have sleep mode for the device. It wakes up every 15 minutes to send data to a server via wifi then go back to sleep. Maybe LiFePO4 batteries will solve the problem ?

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer by asking the authors of the ESP plugin for the Arduino IDE, since they are far more intimate with the internal workings of the ESP-32 and ESP8266 that we are here.

Comment: Alkaline battery will start at 1.5v but very quickly drop to around 1.2v and stay between 1.1 and 1.2 for most of its discharge depending on current until it's flat and it drops below 1.1v.  That means 2xAA is getting you 2.2V to 2.4V for most of the battery's life except the first little bit. You need 3xAA (alkaline, but also most other types) for reliable operation of a 3.3V MCU, plus an LDO. Disable brownout detection if you know what you're doing and know that your application can reach a certain undervoltage without consequence.

Answer (score 2):

For me brownout issue was solved by removing the esp32 from Arduino IDE board manager + removing files from disk and use install procedure "Using Arduino IDE with the development repository" - https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/

I guess it will use newer version of arduino-esp32 that has some brownout protection due to CONFIG_REDUCE_PHY_TX_POWER being activated by default. Also you should probably learn how to decrease wifi power + deep sleep for longer battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's silly but I added a delay to my script before I got the error.

```
Serial.println("Delay 5s Brownout detector was triggered");
delay(5000);
```