# ESP32-S2 Brownout Detector Randomly Triggered in Deep Sleep

Tags: esp32, sleep, espressif

I have thoroughly searched for answers on this over the past couple weeks, and have not been able to find a solution for Arduino.

I'm using an ESP32-S2-Saola-1M Dev board that needs to store a sensor reading in RTC memory, go to sleep for 5 min, and then wake up again and store another reading. Every few hours, it shares its data and starts over.

The issue I'm having is that about 2/3 of the devices I have will randomly wakeup with a POWERON event instead of from the timer, and all of the RTC memory is lost. From searching online, this seems to be a hardware issue that causes the brownout detector to trigger incorrectly.

The accepted solution in the esp-idf is [turning off the brownout detector](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/6179) , but this doesn't seem to be implemented in the ESP32 Arduino core, and using code I've found for [turning off the brownout detector in Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55702/esp32-disable-brownout-detector) causes constant brownouts rather than turning the detector off.

There seem to be solutions if I switch my development environment, but I'd rather not do that at this point in development. Has anyone had luck fixing this issue in Arduino?